# 'Happens before' on Scala constructors: final fields

Tags: scala, final, java-memory-model, happens-before

Java specification mentions that classes having only `final` fields have their constructors in a *happens-before* relation with any thread reading any reference to that object: in other words, it is not possible for the application to see a partially constructed object.

Scala hacks initialization by extracting it to separate methods in order to ensure that 'primary constructor vals' are set before any initializing code *in superclasses*. This is at least one reaason why Scala `final val` doesn't translate always (or ever?) to a Java `final` field.

1. Is there a way to achieve this, i.e. ensure the *happens-before* relation between class clients and its constructors?
2. One which is a reasonably stable feature of the compiler?
3. One which is not writing the class in Java?

Answer (score 3):

> Scala hacks initialization by extracting it to separate methods in order to ensure that 'primary constructor vals' are set before any initializing code *in superclasses*.

In java that doesn't break `final` guarantees as long as `this` doesn't escape from the constructor.
("doesn't escape" means that constructor's code doesn't store `this` in a variable/collection/etc which can be read by another thread)

Also because the JMM is [defined for java language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) and not for the JVM, I'm afraid it only works in languages that compile to java code.